# Invariant violation: Native module cannot be null. (App running problem) 2020

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

[image]

I bought a complete app but when I install it in my own environment then it gets back this error.

Comment: Sounds like a module is not linked or maybe some dependencies are missing. Might be good to add the package.json to the question description to show what version of react native and what dependencies you are using

Comment: I already solved this problem to move my file to a new project. But now I'm stuck in another problem, see the comment below, please.

Answer (score 1):

> Try upgrading from expo sdk 37 to expo sdk 38 by running expo upgrade

Looks like there is an open issue on Github. Try this: [Invariant Violation: Native module cannot be null](https://github.com/react-native-push-notification-ios/push-notification-ios/issues/43)

Answer (score 0):

(I already solved this problem to move my file into a new project). But now I'm fetching a new error. I already replace all ListView component with FlatList, and also I have no Icon or Spinner that's I import from react-native or native-base. But it's getting back this error.

[image]